# centering vertically the abstract element

Tags: vertical-alignment, abstract

How can I put at the center of the page the element abstract?I put it in a blank page but it is at the top. I would center it vertically.any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put the abstract on a page on its own in the middle of the page will depend on the class you are using. With the `article` class you have two ways of having the abstract in the middle of a page of its own.

1. Using the `titlepage` option to the class. The will centre (horizontally and vertically) the title / author and so on, on the first page (the so called "titlepage") and the abstract with be placed on a page on its own as well centred both vertically and horizontally.

   ```
   \documentclass[titlepage]{article}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \author{A. N. Onymous}
   \title{The Title}

   \begin{document}
   \maketitle

   \begin{abstract}
   \lipsum[1]
   \end{abstract}

   \lipsum[2-5]

   \end{document}
   ```
2. You can also do it manually by forcing a page break before invoking the `abstract` environment, however, `\vspace` or `\vfill` at the top of the page do not work and you need to add a \null before the first `\vspace`:

   ```
   \documentclass[titlepage]{article}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \author{A. N. Onymous}
   \title{The Title}

   \begin{document}
   \maketitle

   \newpage
   \null\vspace{\fill}
   \begin{abstract}
   \lipsum[1]
   \end{abstract}
   \vspace{\fill}
   \newpage

   \lipsum[2-5]

   \end{document}
   ```

Note that the `title page option will not entirely centre the abstract but have a smaller space at the top than at the bottom (which look more elegant I think)

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to center an object is to put `\vspace{\fill}` before and after it. So, you could try something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{A Clever Person}
\title{A nice article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{\fill}
\begin{abstract}
This is a profound article.
\end{abstract}
\vspace{\fill}
\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will only vertically align the abstract below the title/author part. If you add a `\clearpage` or `\newpage` after the `\maketitle` it will not work anymore. In this particular instance, loading the class with the `titlepage` option to the `article` class will put the abstract by default vaguely in the middle of a page on its own.

Comment: Just use `\vspace*` in place of `\vspace` in that case.